# IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/.virtualenvs/exampleenv/bin/activate_this.py")

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have use virtualenv for deploying a django app on a vps. The following is the content of wsgi file placed in /var/www/example.wsgi

```
import os
import sys
import site
# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('~/.virtualenvs/exampleenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages')
# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('/var/www/example')
sys.path.append('/var/www/example/example')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'example.settings'
# Activate your virtual env
activate_env=os.path.expanduser("~/virtualenvs/exampleenv/bin/activate_this.py")
execfile(activate_env, dict(__file__=activate_env))
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

But the error.log file shows the following error.

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/var/www/.virtualenvs/exampleenv/bin/activate_this.py")
```

It is looking for virtualenv inside /var/www instead of ~/.virtualenv/.....

I have already checked the path of the exampleenv which exists in ~/.virtualenvs/exampleenv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app is probably running as different user (which home dir is `/var/www/`), so `expanduser` function will use its home dir not yours.

It is not a good practice to put others users files in your home dir. Try to put virtualenv in lets say `/var/www/<your_app>/.venv` or `/var/www/.<your_app>_venv`.